# Dynamically change the color of form fields using Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How to change the Angular reactive form fields text color to "RED" only for few fields(firstname and email) when user sets the form values dynamically for these fields using the **setValue()**. Also need to change the color to "GREEN" of the form field(firstname and email) in case user try to modify/interact.

**But should not change the color for other form fields.**

I have created the stackblitz in the following link

[reactive form updated code in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-tjbza2?file=src/app/formreactive/formreactive.component.ts)

I have created the form like this,

```
<form name="form" [formGroup]="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" [style.color]="getColor('firstName')" (input)="inputChanged($event)"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="email" [style.color]="getColor('email')" (input)="inputChanged($event)" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">phone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="phone" [style.color]="getColor('phone')" (input)="inputChanged($event)" />
          </div>

          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="setFormm()">click here</button>
        </form>
```

component

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-formreactive",
  templateUrl: "./formreactive.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./formreactive.component.css"]
})
export class FormreactiveComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(""),
    email: new FormControl("")
  });

  getColor(frmctrl, color) {

  }

  inputChanged = (e: any) => {

  };

  setFormm = () => {
    this.form.controls['firstName'].setValue('vishnu');
    this.form.controls["email"].setValue("vishnu@hminds.com");
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it "playing" with ng-pristine and ng-dirty. see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes). So, in your .css

```
input.ng-pristine
{
  color:red;
}
input.ng-dirty
{
  color:green
}
```

In your function setForm mark as Pristine all the controls

```
setForm = () => {
    ....
    this.form.markAsPristine({ onlySelf:false }) 
  };
```

NOTE: If is empty the inputs you can give a black cursor

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" 
        [style.color]="!form.value.firstName?'black':null" />

 //and 
 <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="email" 
        [style.color]="!form.value.email?'black':null" />
```

see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-5smkuk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fformreactive%2Fformreactive.component.html)

**Updated** if we want that this happens only in some inputs we can add a class to the input (e.g. called 'advice') class="form-control advice"

Our .css becomes

```
input.ng-pristine.advice
{
  color:red;
}
input.ng-dirty.advice
{
  color:green
}
```

And our inputs like

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control advice" formControlName="firstName" 
                [style.color]="!form.value.firstName?'black':null" />
<input type="text" class="form-control advice" formControlName="email" 
               [style.color]="!form.value.email?'black':null" />
```

I updated the stackblitz

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. it's working as expected but suppose if i have a another field (phone number) and do not want to apply the styles for this field i.e, apply styles only for firstname and email. can you please help me out for this. i have updated the code in stackblitz

Comment: you always can add a class to your inputs, see my updated answer

Comment: great @Eliseo, Its working like charm. The same form converted in to reactive dynamic form yesterday and not able to adding the same functionality. can you please help. stackblitz link:  [dynamic reactive form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-3yl2x5?file=src/app/shared/dynamic-form.component.ts)

Comment: just add the css to dinamic-form.component (you can do in "style") and add as property "advice:true" only in the elements you need the class advice. In input add [class.advice]="prop.advice", I forked your stackblitz in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-zyidmb?file=src/app/shared/dynamic-form.component.ts